# Why does Eclipse keyboard shortcut for "Run Ant Build" only work for certain file extensions?

Tags: eclipse, ant, keyboard-shortcuts, build.xml

If I'm in a .txt file and I do either <kbd>Alt-Shift-X</kbd>,<kbd>Q</kbd> or use my self-created <kbd>Alt-R</kbd> shortcut, it runs the build.xml for that project.

If I'm in a .js file and I do the same thing, it does nothing.

I have tested with different files, filetypes and editors, and it is definitely the file extension that controls whether it works.

Other keyboard shortcuts (with the same "When" of "In Windows") work fine in all files.

Some extensions work (.txt, .cfm, .xml) whilst others (.html, .js, .less, .cfg) don't.

The only link I can see between the working ones is that, when looking in Preferences>General>Editors>File Associations, those that work have a `locked by 'X' content type` next to at least one associated editor.

Upon testing, adding *.js to the "Text" content type enables the shortcut to work for JS files.

**Why does having a "content type" allocated allow a file with a particular extension to run the Ant build file?**

How do I make it work irrespective of the current file type, (without going through and setting the content type for all file extensions plus the names of all non-extensioned files)?

Answer (score 1):

Key bindings don't exist globally, but are defined for a given context. All existing [contexts in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_advext_contexts.htm) make up a hierarchy, e.g. "Editing text" has "In windows" as parent, which has "In Dialogs and Windows" as parent.

If a certain context is activated (a plugin explicitly needs to do that), then all key bindings of this context and of all parents in that hierarchy are available. As the "Run Ant Build" command is bound to the "Working in windows" context, I would *guess* that the non working editors set that context only if a certain content type is active as described by you (which I would rate a bug). Or they define a context which has "In Dialogs and Windows" as direct parent, thereby "bypassing" the "In Windows" context, where your shortcut is defined.

A possible workaround *might be* to change the context of the key binding in preferences from "In Windows" to "In Dialogs and Windows".

Comment: Ah, I didn't know there was a direct hierarchy, just thought it was an implied one. Anyway, I tried changing to "In Dialogs and Windows" but unfortunately it didn't make it work.